# Excel date format issue from multiple files

Tags: datetime, excel-formula

I have data coming in from different versions of a machine in CSV format but each machine (due to their age) provides the date/time in a different format.

```
2020-10-30T13:24:26.874Z

2020-10-30T14:37:27.052Z

10/30/2020 09:29:06

10/30/2020 11:42:47

2020-10-30T14:10:35.422Z

11/02/2020
```

I've used the following formulas to split the date and time into different column:

```
=LEFT(O1399,10)

=IF(RIGHT(O1399,1)="Z",LEFT(RIGHT(O1399,13),12),RIGHT(O1399,8))
```

However some of my date results are coming up as follows:

```
43872.3807

43872.3829
```

We've also had issues where the date is in an American format 10/6/20 (6 November 2020) but the result is  English but still 10/6/2020 (10 June 2020).

Can anyone help with a simple solution of how I can get all of the dates and times into a UK format?

Comment: for a date like **4/1/2020** how can you tell if it is ***UK*** or ***US*** ??